# Converting three-table FULL OUTER JOIN query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to translate this query which works in SQL Server to MySQL. I've circled around it at least 50 times and am stumped and cannot even find a starting point.

The issues in a nutshell:

- It has not one but two `FULL OUTER` joins which MySQL does not do. I
  know this can be emulated some how using `UNION` in combination with `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins.
- It joins the tables on multiple conditions and I am not sure how to add exclusion
  criteria in the `ON` if doing a typical `RIGHT JOIN`

```
SELECT COALESCE(ca.reporting_period, s_p.reporting_period, s_uy.reporting_period) AS reporting_period,
       COALESCE(ca.state, s_p.state, s_uy.state) AS state,
       COALESCE(ca.servicer, s_p.servicer, s_uy.servicer) AS servicer,
       COALESCE(ca.product, s_p.product, s_uy.product) AS product,
       COALESCE(ca.product_group, s_p.product_group, s_uy.product_group) AS product_group,
       COALESCE(ca.portfolio, s_p.portfolio, s_uy.portfolio) AS portfolio,
       COALESCE(ca.channel, s_p.channel, s_uy.channel) AS channel,
       ca.Gross,
       ca.Costs,
       ca.commission,
       ca.commissionable,
       s_p.WAVG_placed_numerator,
       s_p.place_balance AS WAVG_placed_denominator,
       SUM(s_uy.cum_gross) AS gross_uy_num,
       SUM(s_uy.cum_netnet) AS netnet_uy_num,
       SUM(s_uy.cum_commission) AS servicer_uy_num,
       SUM(s_uy.num_accounts) AS uy_den,
       ca.costs_recovered
# INTO adhoc_work.RevenueReport_Legal
FROM   adhoc_work.Cash ca
FULL OUTER JOIN adhoc_work.Summary_placed s_p
 ON  ca.reporting_period = s_p.reporting_period
  AND ca.state = s_p.state
  AND ca.servicer = s_p.servicer
  AND ca.product = s_p.product
  AND ca.product_group = s_p.product_group
  AND ca.portfolio = s_p.portfolio
  AND ca.channel = s_p.channel
FULL OUTER JOIN adhoc_work.Summary_uy s_uy
 ON  ca.reporting_period = s_uy.reporting_period
  AND ca.state = s_uy.state
  AND s_p.state = s_uy.state
  AND ca.servicer = s_uy.servicer
  AND s_p.servicer = s_uy.servicer
  AND ca.product = s_uy.product
  AND s_p.product = s_uy.product
  AND ca.product_group = s_uy.product_group
  AND s_p.product_group = s_uy.product_group
  AND ca.portfolio = s_uy.portfolio
  AND s_p.portfolio = s_uy.portfolio
  AND ca.channel = s_uy.channel
  AND s_p.channel = s_uy.channel
WHERE  COALESCE(ca.reporting_period,s_p.reporting_period,s_uy.reporting_period) BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,-13,NOW(3)),'%Y%m%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(3),'%Y%m%d')
GROUP BY COALESCE(ca.reporting_period,s_p.reporting_period,s_uy.reporting_period)
   ,COALESCE(ca.state,s_p.state,s_uy.state)
   ,COALESCE(ca.servicer,s_p.servicer,s_uy.servicer)
   ,COALESCE(ca.product,s_p.product,s_uy.product)
   ,COALESCE(ca.product_group,s_p.product_group,s_uy.product_group)
   ,COALESCE(ca.portfolio,s_p.portfolio,s_uy.portfolio)
   ,COALESCE(ca.channel,s_p.channel,s_uy.channel)
   ,ca.gross
   ,ca.Costs
   ,ca.commission
   ,ca.commissionable
   ,s_p.WAVG_placed_numerator
   ,s_p.place_balance
   ,ca.costs_recovered;
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your query doesn't quite do a full outer join, because a condition like this:

```
ca.state = s_uy.state
```

requires that `ca.state` be matched.  That is, the outer join is turned to an inner join.

So, to answer your question more theoretically, the simplest method is probably to generate all the rows by using `UNION` among the the table and then use `left join`:

```
FROM (SELECT reporting_period, . . .
      FROM adhoc_work.Cash ca
      UNION   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      SELECT reporting_period, . . .
      FROM adhoc_work.Summary_placed
      UNION   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      SELECT reporting_period, . . .
      FROM adhoc_work.Summary_uy
     ) x LEFT JOIN
     adhoc_work.Cash ca
     ON x.reporting_period = ca.reporting_period AND
        . . . LEFT JOIN
     adhoc_work.Summary_placed s_p
     ON x.reporting_period = s_p.reporting_period AND
        . . . LEFT JOIN
     adhoc_work.Summary_uy s_uy
     ON x.reporting_period = s_uy.reporting_period AND
        . . .
```

Comment: I've tried going down your suggested road. One obstacle is that your suggested `UNION`s require that all fields be identical in the `UNION` sections. As you can see in the original query the first five or so fields are the same, but after that, they diverge. And +1 on your observation that the original query is not really a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. I've started to experiment with just making them `LEFT JOIN`s, and I get a right-ish but different answer in which my MySQL is almost a complete subset of the SQL Server answer. That's where I am at now. I am in over my head on this one.